# NUnit Gets Different Hash Code Values from ReSharper vs Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have a fairly simple GetHashCode() implementation in C# as per Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode). Here is my code:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        if (Title != null)
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + Title.GetHashCode(); // Title is of type string
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

When I run an NUnit test targeting this method through Visual Studio 2013's *Test Explorer* I get one value for the hash code and when I run it through ReSharper 8's *Unit Test Explorer* I get a different value.

Here is my unit test code:

```
[Test]
public void GetGetHashCode_WithLinkAndTitle()
{
    const int expected = -1272954771;
    var target = new Article
    {
        Title = "Rumble News"
    };
    var actual = target.GetHashCode();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

From VS 2013 I get actual == -1411317427 and from ReSharper I get actual == -1272954771.

Why are the values returned from GetHasCode() different across test runners and how can I make them consistent with each other?

Comment: What are the values you are seeing, what is the string in `Title`, and what is the hashcode of `Title`?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQuirk. I added the details in the body of the question.

Comment: When unit testing `GetHashCode` you should only verify that calling it on two objects that are equal returns the same value.  That way you can change the implementation without breaking the test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably using the 32-bit CLR in one test runner and the 64-bit CLR in another. The implementation of `string.GetHashCode` differs between the two. You should *not* depend on them being consistent between runs - they only have to be consistent within a single process.

(It would be entirely reasonable for a `GetHashCode` method to take a seed from a static field initialized randomly on class initialization. So each time you ran the executable you'd get a different set of hash codes - but they would still be consistent within a single app domain.)

Comment: Thank you @jon-skeet. Oddly enough I did try switching ReSharper from 32 bit to 64 bit and back but the result was always -1272954771. And a question about the random seed - how do you unit test that?

Comment: @urig: Basically I wouldn't unit test specific values. Test what you really want - that equal objects give the same hash codes, and unequal ones give different hash codes. Even that's *slightly* brittle, as it would be feasible for unequal values to give the same hash code without it indicating a bug - but it's pretty unlikely.